# python vlc control on windows

Tags: python

I am working on a python project to control vlc player - volume up/down, play/pause, rewind/forward and I have installed python2.7, vlc 3.0.8 32bit on windows 7. this is the code below which is to play the local mp4 file

```
import vlc
instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
Media = instance.media_new('d:\1280.mp4')
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

problem is the keywords - Instance and other functions are not getting highlighted except import and am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\vlc3.py", line 4, in <module>
    Media = instance.media_new('d:\1280.mp4')
  File "C:\Python27\vlc.py", line 1916, in media_new
    m._instance = self
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instance'
```

I am not able to understand please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes instead of backward slashes.

Use:

```
Media = instance.media_new('d:/1280.mp4')
```

Instead of:

```
Media = instance.media_new('d:\1280.mp4')
```